# Define mapping in insert mode that works only with a certain filetype

Tags: vim

*I should know this, but my mind is blank right now ... long night ...*

How to define a mapping that is active only when a certain filetype is active (say, markdown and I wish to define a mapping/abbrev for inserting brackets ][ since I don't have them on my keyboard in my language layout)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To define a mapping effective only in the buffers having certain `filetype`
value, one can use the combination of a filetype autocommand (see `:help
autocmd`, `:help FileType`) and a local mapping (see `:help map-local`).

```
:autocmd FileType markdown inoremap <buffer> (( [
:autocmd FileType markdown inoremap <buffer> )) ]
```

Comment: Figures it had to be something dead-simple ;) Thanks ib.!

Answer (score 2):

The first, mandatory, step is indeed to define buffer local mappings with `:h  :map-<buffer>` as ib said.

Then you have the choice. You can :

- either clutter your .vimrc with autocommands
- or use ftplugins, which is the solution that scales, that can be easily redistributed, and so on.

The first approach is fine when we only use vim for a couple of languages/filetypes and when we have very few mappings/commands/abbreviations/... It's fine the first couple of years in Vim. Past a certain amount of ft-specific settings, the second solution is the one to be preferred.

(BTW, this subject is a duplicate, but I too lazy right now to search for the other posts)

Answer (score 0):

Add where appropriate (e.g. `~/.vimrc`):

```
au FileType markdown inoremap <C-b> [
```

Comment: The command does not work as you probably expect.  Once a buffer with `markdown` filetype is open, it defines the global mapping that works for *any* buffer *even after that Markdown file is closed*!

Comment: @ib Thank you, forgot about that. (I make this mistake fairly regurlarly in my own ~/.vimrc).